# Creating a "Facebook like button" with jQuery mobile's look and feel

Tags: facebook, jquery-mobile, facebook-like

How I can get the Facebook "like button" to look like a jQuery mobile button?
I have a jQuery mobile page with a list of buttons, and I want one of them to be a "like button".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not allowed to change the like button according to Facebook -

https://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php

> While you may scale the size to suit your needs, you may not modify
> the Like Button in any other way (such as by changing the design).

---

If you decide to go ahead with your plan, be aware that if Facebook "catches" you - they **will** take action against your URL/application/page/user.

### Beware - I speak from self experience...

Comment: ok... then how should I go about using a like button in a jquerymobile page?

Comment: In the same way that you would implement the "like button" on any web page.  Simply follow **all** the instructions here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/.  Note that there is also a "Step 2" to the process...